# Notepad++ copy and replace

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ I would like to replace a part of a string with a copy and paste.

For example in a string

> 00000abcde...

I would like to replace `00000` with `17456` copied from another file/

The result is

> 1745600000abcde...

instead what i expect is

> 17456abcde...

Even if I activate the <kbd>INS</kbd> option with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, I obtain a concatenation instead of a replacement.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like you could simply find `00000` and replace it with `1745600000`...

Comment: In my case and i need to replace exactly where the cursor is. The file is an input for a program with anagraphic details such as id, name, tax number end so on.

Comment: Apologies, but the question is unclear to me still. Could you expand on what steps you expect to do? And perhaps a more clear example with multiple cases?

Comment: I try with another example. In a record with ID, NAME, SURNAME and date of birth
64515897  JOHN  SMITH  PARIS                 

I would like to replace PARIS with LONDON.
I copy the word 'LONDON' from another file. Putting the cursor under P of Paris, with a CTRL+V i obtain LONDONPARIS. My need instead is to INSert the word in the string to get.
64515897  JOHN  SMITH  LONDON                 

It works typing with the keyboard but not with CTRL+C/V. Consider i have thousand of this. Thank you

Comment: Something like [this](https://gyazo.com/a1c6e43248c88c8cb669db1dba3eda73)? Also, you could replace all.

Comment: If you want to automatically fetch that input from that other file you're probably using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Matteo Do u mean that for another row it would be to replace NEWYORK with TOKYO?

Comment: Thank you. In my situation i have to keep a specific lenght of the record. Replacing, as you show me, alter it and it take a more time. Anyway i discovering that i don't have this kind of problem with Textpad and i'll use it as best solution. Moreover i see that in Notepad++ i should underline the exact number of character to make the right paste, but is difficult if the words have different lenght.  Anyway thank you for your precious support and sorry if i was not so clear in my previous explanations.

Comment: Hi chingNotCHing. Yes. Is a sequantial record. Any detail in the record must have a specific lenght (filled with spaces). If i replace NEWYORK i paste TOKYO with 2 extra spaces (by keybord). With Textpad is fine but with notepad it concatenate the two words.

Comment: Any other solution for Notepad++ ?